# Какой визуальный редактор выбрать?

Tags: wysiwyg, tinymce, ckeditor

Немогу определиться с выбором визуального редактора для сайта.
Выбираю между TinyMCE и CKEditor. 
Какой посоветуете? Каким пользуетесь?
API без надобности. Плагины писать пока не собираюсь.

Comment: в Yupi есть редактор я его выдернул, 200 раз лучше чем TinyMCE и CKEditor:))

Comment: @bemulima, это что за Yupi такой?

Comment: Меня тоже интересует, что за Юпи. Сок раньше бал. Он? Нет? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После TinyMCE, CKEditor и некоторых других, стал использовать [Imperavi Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/). При полном необходимом функционале, вес его минимальный - 60kb. По сравнению с 300-400kb в других редакторах, в т.ч. и вышеупомянутых, выглядит как насмешка над старшими собратьями. Летает, как пуля, даже при хилом инете.

В общем, лично меня, сейчас палкой не заставишь использовать что-то другое.

Comment: Ну и стоит 100 баксов соответственно.

Comment: Что-то я не могу найти никак про 100 баксов...

Comment: http://imperavi.com/redactor/download/

Comment: Специально засекал время. Скачал триальную версию 12 декабря прошлого года - работает до сих пор. Но если в новых версиях они и поставили защиту, которую при желании можно обойти, то есть другой выход. У них договоренность с разработчиками "Yii", этот редактор там предоставляется бесплатно, как плагин/виджет. Нам виджет полностью не нужен, а интересует один файлик **redactor.js** или **redactor.min.js**, которые вполне [официально стягиваем отсюда](https://github.com/yiiext/imperavi-redactor-widget/tree/master/assets). Кстати, последнее обновление там было сутки назад.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую TinyMCE. Во многих CMS стоит он же. Думаю лучше выбрать его.

*Обновление*

Плюсы: богатый функционал.
Минусы: тяжелый, часто не валиден не во всех браузерах.

Comment: Хотелось бы выслушать аргементированный ответ. Какие плюсы, какие минусы, из вашего опыта использования.

Answer (score 1):

Если без `API` и без плагинов, единственное существенное отличие: `CKEditor` не имеет файлового менеджера в бесплатной версии. То есть, картинку непосредственно в текст загрузить не получится.

В остальном - разницы почти никакой, вы же сами это заметили, иначе бы не спрашивали. )

Comment: Ну на CK есть плагин бесплатный - файловый менеджер. Значит буду его использовать.

Comment: Если нужен файловый менеджер сравнимый с CKFinder можно использовать [elfinder](http://elfinder.org/). Он легко совмещается с CKEditor и бесплатен.

Comment: А в CKEditor нельзя для разных полей формы задать редактор с разным количеством кнопок и функций? Например для одного поля оставить только B, I, U. А для другого поля добавить вставку изображения и т.д. Или можно настроить один вид для свех полей только?

Comment: Про разный функционал у полей уже не актуально. Разобрался.

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    toolbar: 'Basic',
    uiColor: '#9AB8F3'
});

Answer (score 0):

**Бонус**:  статья в стиле CKEditor [v](http://www.orcinus.ru/archive/2012/03-06.asp)  TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, большинство популярных визуальных редакторов имеют избыточный функционал. Поэтому для своих проектов, я всегда использую самописное решение. Создать редактор, который сможет менять цвет, форматирование, размер текста + осуществлять добавление картинок не так уж сложно даже с базовыми знаниями JavaScript, в частности событий документа. Ну а возможность свободно и просто развивать функционал своего редактора, делает это вариант еще более привлекательным.

Comment: Согласен. Но зачем изобретать велосипед, если ненужный функционал можно всегда отключить?